# Adding headers to a csv file

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv

I have a bunch of lists that I've zipped:

```
 zipped = zip(list1, list2, list3)
```

I have a csv file (that already has headers) that looks something like this:

```
Col_1    Col_2    Col_3
data     data     data
```

Now I want to add my zipped lists as column the already existing file, so that it looks like this (with list names as headers):

```
Col_1    Col_2    Col_3    list1    list2    list3
data     data     data     data     data     data
```

I have this code now:

```
with open('existing.csv', 'rb') as infile, open('out_file.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(["list1", "list2", "list3"])
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        row.extend(zipped[i])
        writer.writerow(row)
```

But, unfortunately this overwrites the existing column names.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the exact output you're getting.

Comment: you can use the DictWriter with the [`writeheader()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the existing header which is the first row from your reader object:

```
with open('existing.csv', 'rb') as infile, open('out_file.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    header = next(reader) # get header
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    # create list with old header and new
    writer.writerow(header+["list1", "list2", "list3"])
```

You can also use `itertools.izip` to zip the lists calling next in the for loop to get each subelement:

```
from itertools import izip
zipped = izip(list1, list2, list3)
with open('existing.csv', 'rb') as infile, open('out_file.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    headers = next(reader)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(headers+["list1", "list2", "list3"])
    for  row in  reader:
        row.extend(next(zipped))
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Your own code would not actually overwrite the header, it would add your new header and then the original header zipped with the first subelement from your zipped list directly after.